# Can static function access non-static variables in php?

Tags: php, static-variables

```
<?php
    class Stat
    {
        public $var1='H';
        public static $staticVar = 'Static var';


        static function check()
        {

            echo $this->var1;               
            echo "<br />".self::$staticVar ."<br />";
            self::$staticVar = 'Changed Static';
            echo self::$staticVar."<br />";
        }
        function check2()
        {
            Stat::check();
            echo $this->var1;           
            echo "b";
        }
    }

?>
```

Can i use it like this

```
$a = new Stat();
$a->check2();
```

Comment: How would a static method know what instance of an object it should be accessing to access non-static properties? The simple answer is "No". The more detailed answer is that it should issue a error "use of $this in a static context"

Comment: If it _can_, then PHP is even more b0rked than I thought.  Only an _instance method_ should be able to access _instance_ variables.

Comment: I believe this will throw an error. As you cannot access a non static property from a static method. In c# you could make the property static and access the static property from the static method, but as i recall i dont believe you can do that in php? but im happy to be corrected on that.

Comment: @NicholasKing you can create static properties in PHP, it would basically transform the static class into a singleton, but, yeah, it's possible. Why does OP need a non-static property from within a static method is beyond me though, a static property would do just fine.

Comment: Some of the people above need to get off there high horses. @Jan yes a user can try and see that $this isnt accessible inside a static method however maybe the user above thought that someone with more experience might know a way to do it.  instead of giving the user grief maybe just explain that it isnt possible.

Answer (score 10):

No. A static method will not have access to `$this` (as there is no `$this` to talk about in a static context).

If you need a reference to the current object within the static method, it is not a static method. You can however access static properties and functions from a non-static method.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers say, you can't use the instance methods in a static method. However, you can store a static property being an array of your instances. With some code like this:

```
private static $_instances = array();

public function __construct() {
    self::$_instances[] = $this;
}
```

This way, you can call a method on all the instances in a static method. With some code like this:

```
public static effItAll() {
    foreach (self::$_instances as $instance) {
        $instance->instanceMethod();
    }
}
```

Or you could also just store the last instance. Or some instance depending on the parameters. Whatever, you can just store any instance in a static property, thus being able to then call this instance in your static method.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't. The explanation is simple: there is no access to `$this` in a static method context. You have to find another design to achieve what you want :-)

Comment: You could do a
$instance = new self();
so that you could call the non static variables, it goes against the static element purpose but you could do it haha

Answer (score 0):

No. Static methods and instance objects can not work together in this way. However, you can pass a reference of your instance object to the static method:

```
static function check(&$classReference) //Adding class reference to function
{

    echo $classReference->var1;               
    echo "<br />".self::$staticVar ."<br />";
    self::$staticVar = 'Changed Static';
    echo self::$staticVar."<br />";
}
function check2()
{
    Stat::check($this); //Passing $this
    echo $this->var1;           
    echo "b";
}
```

**However**, just because it's possible doesn't mean it should be done. There's probably another way to achieve what you want in a much better OOP way.